# Carrier Name Doesn't change (9.2.1)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, network

Unable to change Carrier Name using carrier editor (iOS 9.2.1)
My iPhone is not jail broken

Comment: It was last updated 3 years ago, it's not really surprising

Comment: So it is not possible to do in ios 9.2.1??